# What's best for your Video Tracking? Why?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, openframeworks, processing

Best as in reliable, maintainable and fast.
Considering Processing, [VVVV](http://vvvv.org/) or [OpenFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/)?

- I know **Processing** doesn't handle big video frames very well.
- **VVVV** (Nodes use OpenCV) is just for Windows.
- **OpenFrameworks** (OpenCv) is more complicated than the
  above.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by best?  Otherwise, this question may not last long.

Comment: It might be good to give a use case.

Comment: I found the paper: _Enhancing Pd Interactivity with Computer Vision_ very helpful as an introduction to Open CV, although it is focused on PD. (hangar.org/wikis/lab/doku.php?id=start%3apuredata_opencv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to implement your app in Processing and see if it fits your needs and is fast enough. It should a little more easy and faster to write Java instead of C++.
Here can you find how to setup with processing with examples: http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/

If you don't want to code anything you can try VVVV, should be little faster but only on Windows as you mentioned.

If your Processing app is running too slow, you can try openFrameworks.
download it the new OF 007 from http://www.openframeworks.cc/ and check out the setup guide.
If you have done the install you can play around with the openCV examples from

```
<your-OF-folder>/apps/addonsExamples/opencvExample
<your-OF-folder>/apps/addonsExamples/opencvHaarFinderExample/
```

Personally I prefer OF because you can do any custom thing with the most performance, but its good to make your prototype with Processing to see if it works and implement it after that again in OF.

Comment: I'm going to use VVVV for the prototype, since it is faster (coding & GPU) than Processing. I'll definitely release it with OF. Thanks for the Processing-OpenCV library though, didn't knew about that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from your question, VVVV and OF are the options your looking at, but you prefer VVVV's node based programming over OF, but aren't happy that VVVV is Windows only.

Have you considered other alternatives like [MaxMSPJitter](http://cycling74.com/products/maxmspjitter/) or [PureData](http://puredata.info/) ?
Both are similar to VVVV or the other way around :)
MaxMSP has a package for 'optimized matrix operations'(3D/video) called Jitter.
For Jitter there is a [cv.jit](http://jmpelletier.com/cvjit/) free collection of external objects and the samples/tutorials are great.
Similarly PureData has an add-on called [Gem](http://puredata.info/community/projects/software/gem/releases/0.93.0/view), which is similar to Max's Jitter package.
I haven't tried with PureData, but there are [OpenCV bindings](http://www.hangar.org/wikis/lab/doku.php?id=start:puredata_opencv) for it, through Gem.

[image: cv.jit sample]
cv.jit

[image: pdp sample]
pdp OpenCV PureData Bindings - via [Piksel.no](http://www.piksel.no/2009/10/report-from-the-opencv-workshop-at-baltan)

**MaxMSP** uses quicktime on osx and can use directX on windows, but it's commercial.
**PureData** runs on windows/osx/linux, it's free and opensource.

HTH

Comment: PD is always a nice alternative because its free and multi-platform. I don't know how stable is GEM. Can i trust it for a commercial, permanent installation?

Comment: Options are nice. I've used cv.jit, but haven't used Gem much (just a bit of 3D) so I'm afraid I can't assure you it will be a 100% stable for a permanent installation. Might be wiser to ask on the PD [lists](http://puredata.info/community/lists) and [forums](http://puredata.info/community/forums) where you'll find people with a lot more experience in PD/Gem. Sorry I can't aid more.

Comment: @ventolinmono Gem is quite stable, its been around a long time and has been used in lots of commercial work.